# convert images iphone to ipad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am just finish my app for iPhone, now I have to convert it for both iPhone and iPad. I can check the device on runtime. but the problem is that. I don't know what should be size of custom navigation bar (320 * 44 I used in iPhone) ,custom tab bar (320 * 44 i used in iPhone), buttons,table background and my more images size for iPad.

I googling but not get the perfect answer in one place. till now i understand only that image name concept

```
devices without retina:
ImageName.png - For iPhone/iPod
ImageName~ipad.png -- For iPad

devices with retina display:
ImageName@2x.png - For iPhone/iPod
ImageName@2x~ipad.png -- For iPad
```

can any one provide me links from where I get the all information about image size and resolution  for iPad and retina display. like splash screen , icon size , navigation bar size, tab bar size, manage custom images for buttons for both iPhone and iPad etc

It is hard to describe my all image size and resolution problem in this question, but hope you guys understand my problem

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, from the Apple Developer Documentation: [Custom Icon and Image Creation Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html)

Also: [App Icons on iPad and iPhone](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html)

Comment: thanks for quick reply. this link is helpful for me, but this link mostly show the icons size, what is the size on navigation bar in iPad, and how I manage size for my  button(iPhone and iPad). button size in iPhone is 100 x 50.

Comment: There are quite a few sites that show that: http://titaniumtips.com/files/ipad_dimensions_portrait.php or http://titaniumtips.com/files/ipad_dimensions_landscape.php